# Is there a list with Bluetooth GATT Services and their description?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I'm looking for a list of Bluetooth GATT Services with a short description of each. I'm developing a BLE Android App and have to choose the best service.

Comment: You might find it on the [Bluetooth Special Interest Group website](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services/).

Comment: The overviews in the documentaiton can often be helpful: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/

Comment: There used to be much better, more accessible documentation available for each service, as archived here: https://web.archive.org/web/20170711141105/https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt but each individual xml file of detailed documentation is no longer available, and was not archived. I'm very interested in any suggestions anyone has of a similarly friendly way to navigate the new layout of the site?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, there is a list of active specifications [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/?types=adopted). Seems to include services, as well as protocols and profiles.

Comment: take a look at the comments above. it'd improve the long-term value of this answer if you archive the page and each important linked resource.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official documentation available at [Bluetooth](https://www.bluetooth.com/) website. I found this [page](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/) which shows [PDF](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Files/Specification/HTML/Assigned_Numbers/out/en/Assigned_Numbers.pdf?v=1706215305114) document listing all GATT services available. Hope it helps.